# Selenium Python : Unable to get element by id where id = principal

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium, webdriver

For my daily work, I'm trying to create a Python Script which is able to fill in different forms, from different websites.

Here is the thing, for some kinds of website, I'm not able to catch the form elements which Selenium. E.g. in this website : https://econnect.bpcl.in/selfservice-ext/pub/login.html Where I inspect the page with Chrome, the input "User id" box has the id "principal", but Selenium is not able to get it. And when I display the html code of this page, the form looks like being included from another page or something.

I tried to getelementbyid, byname, bycssselector, etc. I also tried to wait for the page to be entirely loaded by using WebDriverWait(driver, 5), but it still do not work.

i also tryied driver.execute_async_script and driver.execute_script

Do you have any solutions or suggestions ?

PS : Even with javascript, I'm not able to get this element by id

Thanks

Comment: first you should display HTML which you get in Selenium - I get only message `This website is secured against online attacks. Your request was blocked due to suspicious behavior`

Comment: Hey there and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some code as example. This makes it easier to find the problem. I get the same error when trying to open the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use x-path, I'm using a chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph?hl=en

To locate the element you want to fill

And then you can use 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("X-PATH").sendkeys("...")`
If you don't want to download a chrome extension you can try to go the HTML script, but I doubt it would work because you said it wasn't working for you...